# Применение оператора += к сложным типам в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
self.daily_consolidator = TradeBarConsolidator(timedelta(days=1))
self.daily_consolidator.DataConsolidated += self.daily_consolidation_handler
algorithm.SubscriptionManager.AddConsolidator(symbol, self.daily_consolidator)
```

Не понимаю как работает вторая строка. Возможности дебага ограничены, не могу посмотреть значение переменной. Могли бы подсказать куда копать?

Comment: ну где-то переопределен оператор `+`, копайте в классе типа этой переменной `self.daily_consolidator.DataConsolidated`

Comment: Куда копать - например эту статью почитать [Руководство по магическим методам в Питоне](https://habr.com/ru/post/186608/), см. подраздел "Составное присваивание". Как конкретно работает: в вашем случае, нужно смотреть в классе TradeBarConsolidator что записано в поле DataConsolidated, и у этого объекта уже смотреть определение метода `__iadd__`.